# How to work simultaneously with 2-3 users on the same project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a team of 3 developers and I want that we should be able to work on the project from our own homes, at any time (or at the same time) and make changes to the project. Till now, we have to mail each other all the updates versions to keep in sync. We are developing the project in Visual Studio 2010 currently and use SQL Express 2008. I searched internet and got some idea about Team Foundation Server but it requires Windows Server. I don't want to get into this mess and I have a Win7 Pc. Please suggest me some easy solutions.

Comment: Use a Version Control System like Git, SVN, Mercurial, etc.

Comment: You may want to put this on progammers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: For future reference, VSTS (Microsoft's hosted version of TFS) is free for up to 5 users.  Not sure that was true at the time this question was asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are any number of low-cost (often free to open source projects) hosted source control providers out there.

Personally I use [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) along with the [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) plugin for Visual Studio.

[Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) and [Git](http://git-scm.com/) are also quite popular and supported within Visual Studio via plugins.

Any of those options can be setup in a few minutes (if you use a hosted solution) and will all work for a small team.

Comment: I am working on projects with c# and ASP.NET. Does that make any tool more preferable over another?

Comment: Honestly I don't feel VS plugin for subversion etc that necessary.  Unlike Visual Source Safe, most version control system do not need to perform "checkout/lock" for every file need to be changed.

Comment: All are well suited for what you are doing

Comment: @Adrian: You still need to commit changes, branch, switch, etc.  It's just more convenient to do that with a plugin.

Comment: Yup, I know there are still some action to do but it doesn't seems anything difficult if I do it in another client (like TortoiseSVN).  Of course it is still good to have plugin doing the works, what I mean is it is not that necessary to have one.  Just like myself, though Eclipse do have SVN plugins, I don't find it helping much in most case, if compared with a separate SVN client (and I mostly do the SVN work in TortoiseSVN  :P ).  And, I am not against your answer, just want to elaborate a bit more on that :)

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the Ankh SVN and its good and easy. I got working on it in a few minutes. But there are a few things I can't understand. Firstly, is there a way to make free repositories for SVN? I used CodeSpaces but its has a limited period of 45 days. I also wanted to know what is the difference between UPDATE and COMMIT in AnkhSVN?

Comment: Also what can be the possible solution to deal with varying connection strings on different machines? If I change connection string in my copy, it will get update to my partners' copy sooner or later and finally there copy will stop working right...

Answer (score 0):

Version Control is what your looking for,and your right there are some complicated solutions out there.  TortoiseSVN isn't too complicated but works well.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the Ankh SVN and its good and easy. I got working on it in a few minutes. But there are a few things I can't understand. Firstly, is there a way to make free repositories for SVN? I used CodeSpaces but its has a limited period of 45 days.
I also wanted to know what is the difference between UPDATE and COMMIT in AnkhSVN?

Comment: Also what can be the possible solution to deal with varying connection strings on different machines? If I change connection string in my copy, it will get update to my partners' copy sooner or later and finally there copy will stop working right.

Comment: UPDATE is going to pull down the most up to date versions of the files on to your machine from the SVN repository, and COMMIT is going to put any changes that you have on to the repository.

Comment: ok, thanks and what about the issue related to connection strings?

Comment: I don't have much experience there. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224374/how-to-vary-connection-string-for-different-work-locations) might help you.